# Hosting multiple sites on server running a website having wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a website that that runs on Apache webserver and supports wildcard subdomains for users. For example:

username.domain.com, username1.domain.com are all valid subdomains that point to my main website in /var/www/production on Apache web server.

Now on the same web server I have dev site at a folder /var/www/dev and mail server (running rainloop) /var/www/rainloop.

I have seperate virtual hosts configured for main production site, dev site and mail server.

But when I run dev.domain.com or mail.domain.com it runs my production site. And the request goes to the route of my main site that handles subdomain requests.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache web server.

Here are vhost configuration for my main site and dev site:

Main Site:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin administrator@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/production
ServerName www.domain.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/domain.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/domain.ca-bundle

</VirtualHost>
```

Dev Site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.domain.com
        ServerAdmin admin@dev.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev
        ServerAlias dev.domain.com

    <Directory /var/www/dev>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

So how can i run both websites separately? My subdomain route dev.domain.com routes to main site due to wildcard subdomains which I don't want. 
I want to run those websites separately i.e when user hits dev.domain.com it should go /var/www/dev folder and any other subdomain request like username.domain.com should go to /var/www/production site.

Do I need to update configuration in vhost?

Thank You!

Comment: There's no indication as to why anything like `X.domain.com` would hit the production site which is `www.domain.com` there's no wildcard that would match `www.domain.com` in `X.domain.com`(unless X=www) are you hitting the apache default page instead by any chance?

Comment: actually I am managing that with my URL Manager in application. 
For example this rule:  'https://<username:(?!www\.)\w+>'.DOMAIN_NAME => 'public/profile' would mean that any request with x.domain.com will go my controller named Public and action named profile

Comment: Yes my question is why does Apache route anything to your application if it doesn't match the vhost in the first place?

Comment: This is what the question is about. Why it is not pointing to correct vhosts when it should. 
dev.domain.com should point to /var/www/dev and production should map to /var/www/production. Because as per my understanding it's job of apache vhost to route request to correct folders.

Comment: If you have only one VirtualHost running defined on `:443`, any `https` request will be served by that virtual host.

Comment: As I asked in my original comment **are you hitting the apache default page instead by any chance?**